# change control's position depending on other control's visibility in a tablelayout panel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a tableLayoutPanel in a form.
It contains 10 buttons.
They are arranged vertically like :

```
btn1
btn2
btn3
btn4
btn5
btn6
btn7
btn8
btn9
btn10
```

Depending on some properties of each button some buttons are visible and some are invisible.

if btn3, btn5, btn6, btn9 are invisible then I want to have arrangement like :

```
btn1
btn2
btn4
btn7
btn8
btn10
```

But instead of that I get arrangement like :

```
btn1
btn2

btn4


btn7
btn8

btn10
```

So how can I achieve the target?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add them to a FlowLayoutPanel control. Changing the visibility on and off of items within this will automatically change the placement for you.

Comment: No, It does not change its position in tableLayoutPanel as they are arranged using percentage.

Comment: I'll second the **FlowLayoutPanel** suggestion.  The controls would automatically shift when you remove some of them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to manage this kind of control is with `WPF` since the controls have a `Visibility.Collapsed` property. Then all control would line up as per their margins. Otherwise you can add and remove them from the control collection of your `tableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not using WPF. And I tried to add and remove controls from tableLayoutPanel. But it I got the same results. The controls are arranged in a row and columns using percentage height and width.

Comment: I realize your not using WPF. I know there is a learning curve, but it would be much more suited for your needs.